# Add cmd command to build Firewall contro with select some things from combobox and textbox like type and no

Tags: c#, cmd

I added the following line at bottom click:

```
     private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      RunCmd("/cnetsh advfirewall firewall add rule name=\"Allowed\" dir=in action=allow protocol='"this.comboBox1.SelectedValue"' localport='"this.textBox1.Text"');
    }
```

What's up with this code ?

when i changed it to :

```
RunCmd("/c netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name=\"Allowed\" dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=80");
```

it worked fine but i need to make the 1st code work so i can Control Type and Port from combobox and textbox

Comment: Maybe you need to concatenate that string?

Comment: oh thanks bro worked fine now with this code             RunCmd("/c netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name=\"Allowed\" dir=in action=allow protocol="+this.comboBox1.SelectedValue+" localport="+this.textBox1.Text+"");

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to use [ProcessStartInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) class to run the command prompt from C# code.

Comment: It's not about use Process Start bro i've already added other cmd commands and working fine the problem when i add this  'protocol='"this.comboBox1.SelectedValue"' localport='"this.textBox1.Text"' '